# A RenderFlex overflowed by 278 pixels on the right. sorununu nasıl çözebilirim?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40pFJ.png)

We design three screens first one is a welcome screen like when the user open the app it shows after that user has two options if he or she has an account then press the login button and it just shifts him to the login screen or if he or she don't have an account then press signup button its transfers to the signup screen. This video shows you how easy it is to build all those using flutter.

..............................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: No Türkçe pls. Also, can you include the relevant widgets in code blocks? Edit; *Also*, I think you should but them in `ListView`, not in `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your row widget and use listview like this

```
 ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: const [],)
```

Answer (score 0):

add that : will work

```
SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
child: Row(
```

for the image in asset did you add the image path in pubspec.yaml
assets:
- lib/images/

[image: describe what to add in pubspec.yaml]